# Check facebook object type

Tags: python, facebook

In my app, I have a form where user should submit a facebook page URL.
How to check that it's correct?
Presently, I'm just checking that it begins with 'http://www.facebook.com'
How can I check that it is a page (where you can become a fan) and not a profile, event or whatever?

I'm using the python api and appengine.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with opening the page with `urllib2.urlopen`?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with just trying to become a fan and letting the user know if this fails?

Comment: @S.Lott : The problem is that I need a facebook FanPage object. If the url is (and it is often the case) a Profile object, urlopen returns a correct JSON but I have no way to check whether it's a FanPage or something else

Comment: @user375348: "I have no way to check whether it's a FanPage or something else" What?  You can't parse the content?  You can't examine the return value?  If you looked at it with your eyeballs, what would you base your decision on?  Can't you write an algorithm to make the same decision?

Answer (score 0):

You could hit up the graph api with the id and see what you get back.

`https://graph.facebook.com/{OBJECTID}`